# Simple question about image_graphviz

Tags: php, graphviz

I'm trying to display the example of image_graphviz [Here](http://pear.php.net/manual/fr/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php), but it doesn't display anything in my page.

Here is my page:

test.php

```
       <?php
        require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';

        $gv = new Image_GraphViz();
        $gv->addEdge(array('wake up'        => 'visit bathroom'));
        $gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee'));
        $gv->image(); 

?>
```

I think there is something wrong with the path, and then i use the absolute path which is "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/PEAR/Image/GraphViz.php". But it doesn't work too.

Is there something wrong?  Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your should try turn the error_reporting to E_ALL

i.e.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I am pretty sure PHP encounter an error but not output it. Also as a good policy it's advice to always turn on E_ALL the error reporting level when you develop.

looking at the doc [there](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/docs/latest/GraphViz/Image_GraphViz.html#methodimage) it seems to pass the image data so make sure your don't have any space at the start of your PHP file, if you do `header` function won't work.

```
*NO_SPACE_HERE*<?php
                require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';

                $gv = new Image_GraphViz();
                $gv->addEdge(array('wake up'        => 'visit bathroom'));
                $gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee'));
                $gv->image(); 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ragez,
I tried the error_reporting, and there is no errors. 
I think i have installed pear image_graphviz, I have tested it in cmd. But actually it doesn't work with php.  I don't know why.

Comment: you might want to edit the `GraphViz.php` and see what is happening there by adding some debug stuff in the file.

Comment: @RageZ, Thanks for your advice. 

I tried and tried, no errors and display nothing. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the GraphVIZ , check the following link i hope it is helpful for you 
http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php